# SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER (FireFox) / NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID (IE) at local Webserver

Tags: apache, ssl, browser, https, twiki

I am running a twiki installation on a Centos9 server that is accessible from our own network via http://twiki.
It is not accessible from outside.
I regularly get the warning SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER (Firefox) or NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID (Internet Explorer, Edge). Of course I can ignore the warning, but after a while it pops up again and that's quite annoying for me.

What can I do to prevent this? I don't actually need https, http would suffice, but I always get redirected to the https version. Is this something the browser does? Or can I configure the web server (Apache) to prevent this?

To be honest, I'm not really a webmaster or network expert. I just need to get the Twiki working. What I've found out so far is that I'm getting the warning because I self-signed my SSL certificate and there is no known trusted author. I also can't get a signed SSL certificate because my server doesn't have a domain like .com or something.

If possible, I would prefer a solution on the server so that each user doesn't have to configure their browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the probem was I ad installed the HttpsRedirectPlugin (https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins.HttpsRedirectPlugin)

After disableing it I can use the http-version